# using skrape{it} to get data from a html

Tags: html, kotlin, web-scraping, html-table

I am making a kotlin web scraping app using skrape{it}.

So far I haver managed to get some information that i need but i cannot get the rest, i need to get a href link from a html table. see below...

```
   <div class="CollapsiblePanelTab" tabindex="0">Today's Interest (1)</div>
   <div class="CollapsiblePanelContent">
   <table width="667px"  class="tabularData">

  <tr>
    <td width="407px" height="21"><a href="link info i need in here">description </a></td>
    <td width="130px">15:28</td>
    <td width="130px">Western</td>
  </tr>
```

I can get the collapsible panel tab info but not the href, i cant figure how to get into the table.

I have done this by doctoring the example code in the libraries github page.

does anyone have any ideas?

my code

```
import it.skrape.selects.el
import it.skrape.skrape

data class MyScrapedData(
    val userName: String
)

fun main() {
    val githubUserData = skrape {
        url = "http://www.website" 

        extract {
            MyScrapedData(
                userName = el("div.CollapsiblePanel").text() 
            )
        }
    }
    println("${githubUserData.userName} is data selected ")
```

Thanks for any info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the syntax i'm assuming you are using version 0.6.0. 
You have to use a more specific css-selector.

```
data class MyScrapedData(
   val userName: String,
   val link: String
)

fun main() {
    val githubUserData = skrape {
        url = "http://www.website" 

        extract {
            MyScrapedData(
                userName = el("div.CollapsiblePanel").text(),
                link = el("table tr td a").attr("href")
            )
        }
    }
    println("selected user: ${githubUserData.userName}")
    println("selected link: ${githubUserData.link}")

    // will print:
    // Today's Interest (1)
    // link info i need in here
}
```

You can find more information about css selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

you could also give version 1.0.0-alpha5 a try. I know it's an alpha version, but it's fully working and you could do things even more elegant.

**EDIT:**
If you want to extract multiple links you can do (using version 0.6.0) it like this:

assuming the HTML you want to parse has following structure:

```
<div class="CollapsiblePanelTab" tabindex="0">Today's Interest (1)</div>
    <div class="CollapsiblePanelContent">
        <table width="667px" class="tabularData">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="1st link">description </a></td>
                <td><a href="2nd link">description </a></td>
                <td><a href="3rd link">description </a></td>
                <td><a href="4th link">description </a></td>
                <td>no link in here</td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change your data classes property link to be of type `List<String>`

```
data class MyScrapedData(
   val userName: String,
   val links: List<String>
)
```

Use `elements` instead of `element` to select all matching occurences of the css-selector and call `eachAttr("href")` to extract the value of all corresponding href attributes.

```
fun main() {
    val githubUserData = skrape {
        url = "http://www.website" 

        extract {
            MyScrapedData(
                userName = element("div.CollapsiblePanel").text(),
                links = elements("table tr td a").eachAttr("href")
            )
        }
    }
    println("selected user: ${githubUserData.userName}")
    println("selected links: ${githubUserData.links}")

    // will print:
    // selected user: Today's Interest (1)
    // selected links: [1st link, 2nd link, 3rd link, 4th link]
}
```

**HINT:**
The artifact id has changed from `core`to `skrapeit-core` from version 0.4.2 and above. I think that's the reason why you couldn't update the version. Thereby you have to add the skrape{it} dependency like this:

using Gradle:

```
implementation("it.skrape:skrapeit-core:0.6.0")
// instead of implementation("it.skrape:core:0.4.1")
```

using Maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>it.skrape</groupId>
   <artifactId>skrapeit-core</artifactId>
   <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I was using 0.4.1 (it was at the top of the list :/ ) i tried getting the alpha build but it wouldn't download for some reason. I did however get the 0.6.0. what do i import to the project please? i ask because attr and link = are highlighted in red even with the vars being declared. Thanks again!

Comment: check that ha ha, I got it to work, there was a missing ,  thanks very much!! just one more question (call me Colombo) If there is more than 1 href link do i just need to declare Link as a list and do a loop to get them all?

Comment: sorry for the missing comma. just typed the code example directly in the browser without syntax highlighting :D
I updated the answer to work with a list of links

Comment: That is brilliant. No problem about the comma haha, I'll have a look at it tomorrow and let you know how I get on. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Christian thanks for the advice I have managed to get all the information I needed from that first part. I have also looked at the CSS selectors and was wondering one thing. Where do I find the information about what to write for eachbselector in your library? For instance if I want to get a certain "I'd" The selector says element #id #firstname is id="firstname" but this doesn't  work... I have tried different ways to write it but to no avail. Any ideas/links to read/teach would be great

Comment: nevermind i got it... '''element("#articleTitle").text()'''